# ¿Por qué ya no se dice "ranacuajo"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Una búsqueda de la palabra *renacuajo* en el DLE indica que originalmente se decía *ranacuajo*:

> [**renacuajo, ja**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VwB32QQ)
>
> Del desus. *ranacuajo*, y este dim. de *rana*.
>
> 1. m. Larva de la rana, que se diferencia del animal adulto principalmente por tener cola, carecer de patas y respirar por branquias.

Me parece que tiene más sentido la palabra *ranacuajo* que *renacuajo*, teniendo en cuenta que es un diminutivo de *rana*.
¿Por qué cayó en desuso la palabra original? ¿Desde cuándo usamos la palabra *renacuajo*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según Corominas, la evolución de palabra fue así:

> Rana > Ranueco > Ranuecajo > Ranacuajo (1400) > Renacuajo (1535).

Ejemplo del CORDE:

> *E quando los quisieren purgar, denles leche de cabras e úntenles los ombligos con fiel de buey, o tomen de los ranaquajos de los ríos e séquenlos, e muélanlos e mézclenlos con del agua, e déngelo a beuer, ca esto los purgará.*
>
> Abraham de Toledo, "Moamín. Libro de los animales que cazan", 1250 (España).

El motivo del cambio aún lo ignoro, pero sí he visto que hacia el siglo XVI hubo varias palabras que cambiaron una sílaba *ra-* inicial por *re-*:

- *[Rebanar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VJAgnTF)* y *rebanada* son probablemente alteraciones de *rabanar* y *rabanada*. El original en latín para la primera es *rapināre*.
- El mismo origen tiene *rebañar*, y de hecho *[rebaño](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VJP30GM)* es de origen incierto pero Corominas afirma que tiene una forma antigua *rabaño*.
- *[Rencor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VwSDQwC)* proviene de *rancor*.
- *[Relinga](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Vqa5LIQ)* proviene de *ralinga*.
- *[Remolacha](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VuPHm6z)* proviene del italiano *ramolaccio*.

También he encontrado alteraciones de *ro-* a *re-*, como en *[reloj](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VqzLaVZ)*, que proviene del catalán antiguo *relotge*, este del latín *horologĭum* 'reloj de arena’, aunque en este caso el cambio se dio antes de llegar al español.

Posiblemente el influjo del prefijo *[re-](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VFxyLmQ)*, ya existente en latín con el significado de "repetición" o "intensificación", pudo influir en estas transformaciones, haciendo las palabras más fáciles de pronunciar al asimilarlas a otras ya existentes que usaban dicho prefijo. No tengo cifras exactas, pero estimo que en el diccionario hay cerca de 3 veces más palabras que empiezan por *re-* que por *ra-*.

Buscando en el CORDE apenas encuentro cinco casos de *ranacuajo* (sin contar el ejemplo anterior y otro caso de *ranacuaios*), dos de ellos relativamente recientes, y otros tres en el siglo XVI. De todos ellos, dos usan la palabra para decir que prefieren *renacuajo* a *ranacuajo*.

También se advierte que en los diccionarios pre-*Autoridades* se prefiere la forma *ranacuajo*. Así aparece desde el *Nebrija* de 1495 hasta el *Stevens* de 1706, pasando por el *Covarrubias* de 1611:

> RANACVAJO, vna sauandija, que parece ser el principio de la formacion de rana, y quajò della.

La forma *renacuajo* aparece en el *Alcalá* de 1505 y ya no vuelve a aparecer hasta el *Sobrino* de 1705. El *Autoridades* de 1737 ya establece la definición de *renacuajo* con la nota "Covarrubias le llama Ranacuájo". De hecho la definición de *ranacuajo* aparece pero redirige a *renacuajo*, y así lleva desde entonces.